# BasicAuthentication & ApiAuthentication per method in Swagger-Net in .Net MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, swagger, swagger-net

As shown in https://petstore.swagger.io/, apis of the **PET** controller get authenticated by **OAuth2**, but that of the **STORE** controller, gets authenticated by **ApiKey**.

I want to achieve the same using `IOperationFilter` in **.Net MVC** (and *not .Net Core*).

Though I am able to turn on the BasicAuth for one API, but couldn't turn off the ApiKey Auth for the same. May be I am not able to find the correct documentation of using the tool.

Could someone point me towards the correct documentation please.

**Swagger-Net** version **8.3.35.101**